# Is there an alternative to OBEX?

Tags: java, bluetooth, obex

I’m programing a desktop application to communicate with a stethoscope using Bluetooth.
Initially I would like to use OBEX, but I’m verify the services available, using the code in this page:
http://www.jsr82.com/jsr-82-sample-bluetooth-service-search/#more-21

I got the following result:

```
*Starting device inquiry...
Device Inquiry Completed. 
Bluetooth Devices: 
1. 002484006FFB (M3200 0010030000286675         )
Choose the device to search for Obex Push service : 1
Searching for service...
Device does not support Object Push.
BlueCove stack shutdown completed*
```

Someone know what alternative to OBEX I have to transfer a file, from a stethoscope to a desktop application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ask the manufacture how the stethoscope behaves.  What profile does it use and does it act as client or server.  If it uses OBEX, I might be that it's a client and thus it sends to a OBEX server device in range, perhaps with a particalur device name or ServiceName...

LATER, from the documentation ([product pages](http://solutions.3m.co.uk/wps/portal/3M/en_GB/Littmann/stethoscope/electronic-auscultation/model-3000-series/) and [3200 User Manual](http://multimedia.3m.com/mws/mediawebserver?jjjjj4MRbvYK15LlFp6qD56SxNMIxvMR&NkjxNkjxjjjjjj--)) that seems to be the case.  Pair the stethoscope to a PC device, run the software there, and the stethoscope connects to it.  Also seems a bit like it might not be OBEX given the real-time aspects possible...

If you have the software app for the PC, do a SDP query for all records on the PC without and with the software running and see what service the app is using...

Answer (score 0):

it might support SPP (Serial port profile).
Not sure what you are trying to do, because the application on the stethoscope might not talk to your application , unless you know the appreciation level communication details.
hope it helps